# ANR timeout too long

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I think I'm being a bit daft here, but I  don't understand why I'm getting faulty ANR timeout values.
Example one:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  while(true);
}
```

I run this code and trigger a touch event on another view. I will get the ANR after ten seconds, whereas I expected five seconds.

Example two:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(60*1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Again, I run the code and trigger a touch event. This time I will not get an ANR at all.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: What do you want to do with `while(true);`??

Comment: i suggest you remove Thread.sleep(60*1000);. Use a handler if you want to run a operation every few seconds

Comment: Ok, I will try to clarify - I'm not trying to avoid an ANR with this code, I'm trying to verify the ANR behaviour. Both of these examples _should_ trigger an ANR, but only the first one does, and the timeout is twice what it should be.

Comment: Can I ask what device and API level you're using? I just tried both your examples on a 2.3.3 emulated device and they both worked as expected (ANR after 5s).

Comment: @flightplanner, I'm testing on a Nexus 4 running 4.2.2. Unfortunately that is the only device I've got available at the moment. I will try it on the emulator and on a few other devices to see if I can narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I don't have any physical devices to hand right now, but have tried a few emulated devices and it seems to work as expected on all those I've tried (including a 4.2), so I'm beginning to suspect a bug on the particular configuration you're using.

Comment: @flightplanner, thanks for your help. I've just tried it on a 4.2 emulator, and I get the same results as on my Nexus 4. Older versions of the emulator seems to produce the expected result, though. Both the phone software and the emulator are official builds. The fact that the code works in your emulator is a bit worrying. I assume that you are also using the emulator that comes with the SDK?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the standard emulator that comes with the SDK.  I did see occasional fluctuation up to about 7 seconds when using the 4.2 emulator, but I always got an ANR within 10s with both the while(true) and Thread.sleep code.